# Identify a single textView (by distinguish from others) in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, textview, attributes

I need to distinguish a single textView by the others, say in a group of four.

Obviously the textView is never the same so I need to set programmatically an identifier (I used "tag" attribute in vb.net to achieve this).

In Android Studio I can see the "tools" attribute (which I can fill with any text without getting errors) but I wasn't able to set it by code (it doesn't show in the hints).

Please give me a way to set "tools" attribute or another way to identify the chosen textView.

Comment: `View` has `getId` and `setId`. There is also `getTag` and `setTag`, though tags need not be unique.

Comment: @Sweeper Great hint! Anyway Android Studio suggested me to use textView.tag instead of setTag. I'll let you know, but I think you can post as answer so I can accept it ;)